# Why Huffman's coding algorithm takes more bit than the original size?

Tags: algorithm, huffman-code

My given string is "Today_is_Monday". If I apply Huffman's coding algorithm to this string.
Without encoding, the total size of the string was `(15*8) = 120` bits.
After encoding the size is `(10*8 + 15 + 49) = 144` bits.

As I know Huffman's algorithm uses to reduce size. But why the encoded size is more than its original?

More details I have done are given below
[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Yes: if your input string has low-frequency characters, the output string can be longer.

Comment: How does the 10*8 come about? I can speculate that the 10 is the number of symbols - how is each symbol and population count represented within the 8 bits? --- Anyway, regardless of the representation, the need to pass a decoding table along with the data causes an overhead, which in turn means that messages must be above a certain length before Huffman encoding pays off - the longer the message, the less of an overhead.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError I think that's how OP encodes the leftmost column of the Huffman table, 10 ASCII characters is the 10 different symbols used (T, o, d...).

Comment: It's actually a little worse than 144 bits, since you didn't include an end symbol to mark the end of the compressed data, or the alternative, which is a symbol count in front of the data. Another source of overhead that is significant for such a short string. You would also need that for your uncompressed string, either a leading count or a trailing zero to mark the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text is too short and the probability distribution function *looks* uniform. If the frequencies of occurrence are (more or less) the same, the input string gets very close to random noise. It is impossible to compress random noise in a general way, compression will most likely be longer than the input sequence, because one also need to add some metadata, like an encoding table.

In contrast, consider encoding a string that is: `aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa`.

If one tries to encode a longer general English text, one would notice at some point, the encoded string size will start to get dramatically shorter than the original text. This is because the encoded sequence frequencies will start to make a much higher impact - the most frequent character will be encoded with the shortest possible code and because it is repeated a lot, its shorter size will dominate the size of the original character.

Answer (score 2):

Huffman encoding optimizes the message length, *given the frequency table*.  What you do with the frequency table is up to you.

Applications for very short messages often assume a static frequency table that both the transmitter and receiver know in advance, so it doesn't have to be transmitted.

Applications that need to send the frequency table often perform additional optimization.  It's possible to communicate the tree by transmitting just the lengths of each symbol in alphabetical order.  The lengths themselves can then be Huffman-encoded.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reversible compression algorithm that is guaranteed to compress all possible inputs.  If there was, then you could repeatedly feed it its own output and eventually reduce any input file to 1 bit.  For *any* initial input file.

Hence, there must be some inputs that cannot be compressed by any particular algorithm.

As others have explained, you have found an input that Hoffman cannot compress.